# Qt uses the API function provided by the wkhtmltopdf library, and calling the "wkhtmltopdf_convert()" function will cause the application to exit

Tags: c++, qt5, wkhtmltopdf

Qt uses the API function provided by the wkhtmltopdf library. When calling the "wkhtmltopdf_convert()" function, it will cause my originally running application to exit (the exit code is 0), which causes the program to automatically exit every time I convert. Is there a solution to this

My Qt version is 5.15.7

Additionally, I directly pull and compile from the source repository of wkhtmltopdf using qmake and make

Here is my main code

```cpp
void HtmlToPdf(const char *src, const char *tar) {
    wkhtmltopdf_global_settings* gs;
    wkhtmltopdf_object_settings* os;
    wkhtmltopdf_converter* c;

    wkhtmltopdf_init(false);

    gs = wkhtmltopdf_create_global_settings();
    wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(gs, "out", tar);
    wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(gs, "margin.top", "2cm");
    wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(gs, "margin.bottom", "2cm");
    wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(gs, "margin.left", "2cm");
    wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(gs, "margin.right", "2cm");

    os = wkhtmltopdf_create_object_settings();
    wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(os, "page", src);

    c = wkhtmltopdf_create_converter(gs);

    wkhtmltopdf_set_progress_changed_callback(c, progress_changed);
    wkhtmltopdf_set_phase_changed_callback(c, phase_changed);
    wkhtmltopdf_set_error_callback(c, error);
    wkhtmltopdf_set_warning_callback(c, warning);

    wkhtmltopdf_add_object(c, os, NULL);

    if( !wkhtmltopdf_convert(c) )           // this will exit
        fprintf(stderr, "Convertion failed!");

    printf("httpErrorCode: %d\n", wkhtmltopdf_http_error_code(c));

    wkhtmltopdf_destroy_converter(c);

    wkhtmltopdf_deinit();
}
```

I hope my application can call this function without being exited